# Prevent automatic screen lock in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am downloading some contents from the server and after sometimes the screen is locked down. The downloading is happening in the background. And I am showing a video after download completes. And in this case, i.e, when the screen is locked, after downloading completes all I can see is just a black screen (After unlocking).
In the simulator, I could see the video playing.. but the video has already been started.

**Is there any way to prevent the iPad from being Screen Lock? (Other than setting it in the settings menu)**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This may help you

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```